# TCP request sent by client but never reveived by server using JavaFX client and Python server

Tags: java, python, sockets, javafx, python-sockets

I'm not very experienced in Java and javafx but I'm trying to create a chat app using a JavaFx client and a python server.
I use a controller to interact with my app :

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class MainController implements Initializable {
    private Connection mainConnection;

    @FXML
    private TextField messageEntry;

    @FXML
    protected void sendMessageAction(ActionEvent e) {
        mainConnection.sendMessage(messageEntry.getText());

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        try {
            mainConnection = new Connection("127.0.0.1", 1500);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mainConnection.sendMessage("Connection initialized");

    }

}
```

Here is my class Connection :

```
public class Connection {
    private OutputStream outputStream;
    private PrintWriter printWriter;
    private Socket socket;

    public Connection(String ipadressString, int port) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        socket = new Socket(ipadressString, port);
        outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        printWriter = new PrintWriter(outputStream);

    }

    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
        printWriter.print(message);
        printWriter.flush();

    }

}
```

In my controller initialization, I create a Connection object and I call :`mainConnection.sendMessage("Connection initialized");`
My server receive correctly this message. Then, when I click the button and call the method `sendMessage()`, nothing happen and my server doesn't receive anything but no error appear... Moreover, the method is correctly called because the `System.out.println(message)` print the message in my console.

Python server

```py
import socket

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(("127.0.0.1",1500))
server.listen(5)

connexion, info = server.accept()
print(info)

while True :
    message = connexion.recv(4096)
    if (message != b""):
        print(message)

connexion.close()
server.close()
```

firstOverview.fxml file :

```fxml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="671.0" prefWidth="789.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.rfaur.spokee.MainController">
    <children>
        <TextField fx:id="messageEntry" layoutX="91.0" layoutY="630.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="683.0" />
        <Button layoutX="14.0" layoutY="630.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#sendMessageAction" text="Envoyer" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

And my mainApp Class :

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class mainApp extends Application {
    private static BorderPane root;
    private AnchorPane messagePane;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        root = (BorderPane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("view/mainView.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        primaryStage.setTitle("My app");
        setScene();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void setScene() throws Exception {
        messagePane = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("view/firstOverview.fxml"));
        root.setBottom(messagePane);
    }
}
```

*What I tried :*

I tried different things and it seems like the problem comes from the server. I tried to catch TCP request using Wireshark and when I click my Send Button, there is actualy a request catched by Wireshark. I guess that means my app correctly works...

I see on wireshark that the first message sent with `mainConnection.sendMessage("Connection initialized")` in my `initialize` method comes from the port 63867. That message is correctly received on my server.
But when I try to send a message using the button, the source port is now 63868 and nothing is received on th server... Maybe the problem comes from that alteration.

I have tried to make 3 different servers using Java and Python but no one works... So my app sends a message but it is never received by my server.
I'm using a Connection Sharing from my phone... Don't know if it's impacting.

Sorry for spelling mistakes, I've done my best but I'm not good in english!

Comment: You can check if the socket is closed with, for example, `System.out.println(socket.isClosed())` in your `sendMessage()` method. Can you create a very simple version of your server (e.g. one that just logs messages it receives to `System.out`) and a very simple FXML file and application class so other users can reproduce the issue?

Comment: I did a real quick test of this (using a simple server written in Java), and it worked fine. So I think the issue is in your server code.

Comment: Thank you for answer ! `socket.isClosed()` returns `false`. My python server seems to work because I tested it with a simple python client and it worked very well... I tested my server with a simple java client and it worked too... I will edit my post and add the mainApp class, the Fxml file and the python server maybe !

Comment: That works just fine for me, either with the python server you posted or with an equivalent Java server. Note your python server can only handle a single connection (because it blocks listening for data from the first connection it accepts), so you need to exit it and restart it each time you restart your JavaFX client (or any other client). I'm guessing what you did is start the server, test it with a python (or other client), then start your JavaFX app and try to test it from there.

Comment: Yes I know my server is very simple because it's the beginning of my project : )
I restarted my computer to ensure every connections were closed. Then I started my python server and then I started my app and the problem still is.
I also created a basic java server and tested it with a simple java client and everything was ok but when I start a serve with my app, it doesn't work...
I test my app with 3 different servers : 1 python server, 1 java server I made and 1 java server I took on the web. Those three server are working fine with basic client but I still have the problem with my app.

Comment: Again, works just fine for me.

Comment: Ok so I don't know what is happening for me... I tried everything, I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it was just a mistake coming from me... I was calling two times my controller. I realized and it's all ok now !